# Bootstrap Modal and iframe / form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I can´t figure out why this isn´t working...I put this modal at the end of my Content and tried to put a form into it...however: It works all fine UNTIL i add my `iframe` (which is my form target).

Additional: I also just found out, that nothing below this is displayed anymore (footer)...on another site without that modal and a form everything just works fine...

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">MyForm</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <iframe width="320" height="240" style="display: none;" name="submitter">
        <form target="submitter" method="post" action="template/submit.php" style="height: 1px;">
            <div id="formular">
Text n Stuff
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="error">
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Schlie&szlig;en</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></form>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing iframe closing tag...

```
</iframe>
```

Comment: ouh how can I be this stupid...just overlooked this...thanks...works fine now.